# How can we accept USDTZ in smartpy smart contracts, is it even posible?

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I was working on a token sale, so is there any way we can accept USDTZ as a mode of payment for the tokens?

Comment: Yes, you will need to listen to USDTZ balance updates to the destination account.